# Remove Google Analytics cookie

Tags: iis, cookies, google-analytics, http-status-code-403

We had an wrong script inserted by Google Tag Manager on our page, that caused 403 error. The script was removed and after wiping out the cookies (or just _gs cookie) our page works fine.

The problem is that the users, who entered the page when we had the wrong script still have the _gs cookie, and they still get 403 error.

How can we make their browsers remove that cookie, while our index page is not even reached?

The setup is a Sitecore CMS set up on IIS 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifying the root cause helped to solve the problem.
Our application is set up on Azure VM, but the connection is through Application Gateway, which has a firewall. Apparently, the firewall considered the content of the mentioned _gs cookie suspcious, and it was the Application Gateway, that returned 403, and not the IIS itself.

Adding the _gs cookie to the whitelist solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "expiring" the cookie. All that would need to be done is add that cookie back but with the expiration date set to a date/time in the past. That way the cookie would be treated as expired and would pick up the new value if it exists.

Comment: That was my idea, but the problem was that I couldn't get my code executed, because the request didn't reach my page.